# Error al instalar CodeIgniter en XAMPP en modo manual

Tags: codeigniter

estoy intentando instalar CodeIgniter en XAMPP de modo manual y me ha salido este error al entrar en la página de inicio "http://localhost/cim4/":
¿Alguién sabría que tengo que hacer para arreglarlo?

```
SYSTEMPATH\CodeIgniter.php at line 219

212         foreach ($requiredExtensions as $extension) {
213             if (! extension_loaded($extension)) {
214                 $missingExtensions[] = $extension;
215             }
216         }
217 
218         if ($missingExtensions !== []) {
219             throw FrameworkException::forMissingExtension(implode(', ', $missingExtensions));
220         }
221     }
222 
223     /**
224      * Initializes Kint
225      */
226     protected function initializeKint()
```

Comment: puedes instalar codeigniter de 2 formas con las 2 formas te muestra el mismo error?

Comment: Por lo que yo sé (y podría equivocarme) se puede instalar vía manual o via Composer. Como mencioné anteriormente yo lo hice vía manual cambiando valores tal y como se especifica en este video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aK_O6qx_FI&list=PLCTD_CpMeEKTFN5TDeOP-wP_hU0_9VoWg&index=3
y cambiando en .env de "production" a "development"
 CI_ENVIRONMENT = development
Pero de ahí no consigo pasar. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Al final encontré la respuesta: 
Habría que colocar la siguiente linea en php.ini:
extension=intl
Con eso ya se ve la pagina de bienvenida.

Answer (score 0):

Al final encontré la respuesta: Habría que colocar la siguiente linea en php.ini: `extension=intl`
.Con eso ya se ve la pagina de bienvenida.